# ReditectToRoute in symfony2 keep showing old url parameters

Tags: symfony

I have a Symfony2 application,  there is a page article which has 2 route parameters id and slug, when a user mistype the slug he is redirected to the same route with the correct slug parameter using the function ReditectToRoute(), the redirect is done with the new parameters but the url shows always the old values of parameters, i don't know what's wrong?
Here is the code i use in my controller :
If(article->getSlug()<> $slug )
   $this->ReditectToRoute('article',array('id'=>article->getId(),'slug'=>article->getSlug()), 301);

Comment: Can you shwo your code?

Comment: Show code please

Comment: I edited my question to contain the code i used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well it's embarrassing but i forgot to return the response so i just added return redirectToRoute(...)